# Using inheritance

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I have classA that has some variables declared in its .h file (arrays, strings, etc), and in its .m file it has methods that preform operations on these variables.

I am about to create classB, which is going to need all the same methods in its .m, and most of the same variables in its .h.

I have been doing reading but am still confused.  I know I need to use inheritance, but I am not sure exactly how.

What I think I need to do:

**classA.h**

```
@interface classA{
NSMutableArray *myArray;
NSString *myString;
}
```

**classA.m**

```
#import classA.h
@implementation classA

-(void)displayArray{
for(int x = 0; count < [myArray count], x++){
NSLog(@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:x];
}
```

**classB.h**

```
#import "classA.h"
@interface classB{
}
```

**classB.m**

```
#import "classB.h"
#import "classA.m"
@implementation classB

-(void)viewDidLoad{
[self displayArray];
}
```

I want classB to have its own `myArray` and then when `displayArray` is called in classB, it would display classB's `myArray`.  And I need to repeat this for many more classes, but I am just trying to get it work with A and B right now.

Thanks.

---

Edit:  I just made up this example, it is not the actual code.

Comment: you don't need to `#import` the `classA.m` file in the **classB.m** file.

Comment: thanks, this combined with what @holex said is doing the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is simple as an 1x1 :)

```
@interface classB : classA {

// ...

}

// ...

@end
```

and after it every instance of the `classB` has everything what the `classA` has.

Comment: Okay I added that, and it now recognized the `displayArray` method in classB.  But I get an error: `linker command failed with exit code 1`

Comment: is there any more details of the error? this is very generic... many things can cause it: from a missing header, to a wrong compiler configuration...

Comment: Thanks, I added this and removed the `#import "classA.m"` from the classB.m and everything is working.  I think the error was because I was importing something twice

Answer (score 0):

Your classB need to subclass classA and that's all.

In your classB class you may modify the myArray ivar, the displayArray method will log it correctly.